# Video processing pipeline

Tags: java, spring, video-processing, spring-cloud-dataflow

I would like to build a video processing pipeline. Meaning I have one webcam stream as input, and I do some processing on it, such as face detection and recognition. More than one processing, and there can be processing in parallel. These are basic use-cases for now, but it will grow in the future.

I want to do it live, I want the result of my processing as soon as possible.

Coming from Java/Spring world, I had a look at Spring Cloud Data Flow.

My question: is Spring Cloud Data Flow the right choice for this use-case? I saw that communication between Source/Processor/Sink is done through either Rabbit or Kafka Binder. Would they handle image/video messages? Or is there any other Binder that would fit better?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, it really depends how you write your components, the short answer is yes, it can be used for it, as a matter of fact we actually have a very large customer that uses it for this use case.

Given the right hardware and configuration, SCDF handles hundreds of thousands of messages per second. It's built to support horizontal scalability, so if you intend to split your video frames captured somehow (we don't provide this out of box) and send each image to a processor to be analyzed by a framework such as OpenCV or TensorFlow. It's a very common use case actually.

You'd probably be better off starting with kafka, just because your data may be a bit too big for rabbit which handles queues in memory, so having a broker that writes to disk might be a better fit.

Besides that, you just need to write the video capture logic and the processors and tie them together using the DSL.

Comment: @Bertrand88: +1 to Vinicius' recommendation. Start with Kafka and work your way through it. We used to have [`videocap` module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd-modules/tree/master/videocap) that we supported in Spring XD (the legacy design; SCDF's predecessor). It can be utilized as a reference, but of course, it needs to re-implemented per Spring Cloud Stream [programming model](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Chelsea.SR2/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#_programming_model).

Comment: Here's all the [out-of-the-box apps](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/) that you also use as a reference. It'd be great to contribute the new app back to the OSS/community.

Comment: Thanks @vinicius-carvalho and sabby-anandan !
Any info shareable on this very large customer and use case?
I'll give it a try. But I have trouble imagining I would get to a near real time processing if Kafka begins to write images to disk... I guess I will have to tune Kafka's parameters to keep in memory, and write to disk as a last resort.
Any reason why the videocap module has not been re-implemented in SCDF?

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is a slightly outdated thread, but for completeness you can find some example SCDF `webcam-source` implementation [here](https://github.com/tzolov/image-processing). Also there you can find a `image-viewer` SCDF sink application that can be used as a player. They both use Rabbit as a binder.

Mind that those are just experimental apps. I've been using them for demoing various Tensorflow image processing pipelines.